# Jquery clone a table with specific row class

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hey how can I clone the table named teamselectiontable with just the table rows that have the class "chosen", and modify another table and replace its contents with the table rows found.  But keeping the class names of "row" in the appended table.

```
<table id="teamselectiontable">
  <tr class="chosen">content</tr>
  <tr class="something">content</tr>
  <tr class="something">content</tr>
  <tr class="something">content</tr>
  <tr class="something">content</tr>
  <tr class="chosen">content</tr>
  <tr class="chosen">content</tr>
</table>
```

To a table like below.

```
<table id="talentselection">
  <tr class="row"></tr>
  <tr class="row"></tr>
  <tr class="row"></tr>
</table>
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(".chosen").clone().attr("class","row").appendTo("#talentselection")
```

or if you want to replace the whole contents of the target table

```
$("#talentselection").html($(".chosen").clone().attr("class","row"));
```

Please note you need tds in your table markup for this to work

```
<tr><td class="chosen">content</td></tr>
```

Comment: so with this I can still keep the table rows with the class? as long as I have the table data. As above you have moved the class to the table data?.

Comment: This will clone the "chosen" rows, replace the class name on them to be "row" and append them to the target table. If you just want to get the value of "chosen" rows and copy just the contents to a pre-existing target table you will need to do it a bit differently.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming I've understood what you're trying to do, you can use the [`clone`](http://api.jquery.com/clone/) method to clone the selected elements, and the [`appendTo`](http://api.jquery.com/appendTo/) method to append the clones into another element:

```
$("#teamselectiontable .chosen").clone().appendTo("#talentselection");
```

The elements in the original selection will be unaffected. Note that in its current form the above code will not clone any events bound to the matched elements. If you wanted to clone the elements with their events, just pass `true` into the `clone` method.

**Update** (see comments)

To change the class name on the cloned elements, you can use the `removeClass` and `addClass` methods:

```
$("#teamselectiontable .chosen")
    .clone()
    .appendTo("#talentselection")
    .removeClass("chosen")
    .addClass("row");
```

Comment: Will the appended table #talentselection, now consist of the table rows with the class named chosen? or will they be with the class "row", because I want to to clone the table rows with the class "chosen" but into the #talentselection table but with the new class of "row".

Comment: @user969729 - No they would have the same class. I've updated the answer with a solution.

Comment: @JamesAllardice Assuming he wishes to keep his 3 "predefined" rows, this solution will not quite suffice him. How about cloning the contents, then append these one at a time to the destination rows?

Comment: The rows that are already inside of the #talentselection table I wish to be replaced with the ones found. This seems to add the cloned rows onto it?.

Comment: but were nearly there :) haha